# Bintray API blocking HEAD method requests

Tags: bintray

Bintray api doesn't seem to work for HEAD method requests.
I am trying to download a few files from bintray and would like to see if the url exists before. For this I am using HEAD method request to a bintray api to see if url exists. 

`curl  https://api.bintray.com/packages/:subject/:repo/:package/files`

gives a response status of 200, but 

`curl -X HEAD https://api.bintray.com/packages/:subject/:repo/:package/files`

gives a response status of 400. 
Does anyone know how to get around this. I certainly don't want to do a GET request as that would mean downloading the whole content from bintray.

Answer (score 2):

[Bintray documentation](https://bintray.com/docs/api/#_get_package_files) states that it uses the `GET` method, so `HEAD` might be blocked.

From the use case you have mentioned you need headers only, this can be done using curl's `--head` or `-I`.

You can use the following `curl --head https://api.bintray.com/packages/:subject/:repo/:package/files` to check if the URL exists. You can also use `curl -I https://api.bintray.com/packages/:subject/:repo/:package` or query the repository for your package.